# Calling a function of a GameObject by button click in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a GameObject in my scene, it contains a script.

The name of the object is - WoodCutter(Clone), the script name is WoodHarvester.cs.

I also have the UI Canvas with few objects. The code instantiates new button in the canvas and I'm trying to add a onclick listener. It should happen so that if button is clicked a script happens in this exact GameObject, since it may happen so that multiple same GameObject will be placed. So the current code I have:

First of all I'm declaring a variable of the gameobject:

```
public GameObject thisBuilding;
```

Then I'm setting current gameobject to this variable:

```
thisBuilding = this.gameObject;
```

Then I'm creating a button placed in the UI Canvas:

```
    Transform btnTransform = Instantiate(btnTemplate, transform);
    btnTransform.SetParent(btnParent, true);
    btnTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    btnTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition);
    btnTransform.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Grow";
```

It all works until now, but then I'm trying to add a listener to this button:

```
     btnTransform.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => {
        thisBuilding.GetComponent<WoodHarvester>().GrowButton();
     });
```

But then it gives an error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

So the idea was that for listener I'm adding a script of this certain object. But it doesn't work.

Where is error and how to fix this? Thanks for any advice or clue!

UPD.: GrowButton() function:

```
public void GrowButton() {
    Debug.Log("Growth!");
}
```

UPD2.: Issue solved! The problem was that button was empty. Changed the line to:

```
Button thisButton = btnTransform.Find("button").GetComponent<Button>();
```

Comment: Isolate all the possible references that can be null.   Move each reference into a variable, then you will know which one is null.  Creating a variable to store `gameObject` in is unnecessary, you can always reference it as `gameObject` because it refers to the GameObject the script is attached to.

Comment: Yes! Indeed! It seems that "btnTransform.GetComponent<Button>()> returns null. It's weird! I'm sure it exists on scene.

Comment: Obvious question but does the `btnTransform` prefab have a button script attached? Could it be the prefab has a parent and the button is lower down?

Comment: Well, basically, btnTransform consists only of empty button with placeholder text.

Comment: If the button component is not directly on the btnTransform object, you likely need `GetComponentInChildren<Button>()` instead.